Optional Data Exception false when reading object from file
I am trying to read objects from file to display them on a jpanel but I am having a hard time deserializing them.
public static void saveFile(Screen screen)
{
    JFileChooser find = new JFileChooser();
    find.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    int result = find.showSaveDialog(find);
    if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == result)
    {
        File file = find.getSelectedFile();
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            os.writeInt(screen.getObjects().size());
            ImageIO.write(screen.getBackgroundImage(), "png", os);
            for(Item i : screen.getObjects())
            {
                i.removeImage();
                os.writeObject(i);
            }
            os.close();
            fo.close();
            for(Item i : screen.getObjects())
            {
                i.setImg();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public static Screen loadFile()
{
    JFileChooser find = new JFileChooser();
    find.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    int result = find.showOpenDialog(find);
    if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == result)
    {
        File file = find.getSelectedFile();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            int items = is.readInt();
            BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(is);
            Screen screen = new Screen();
            screen.setBackground(background);
            for(int i = 0; i <= items; i++)
            {
                Item object = (Item) is.readObject();
                object.setImg();
                screen.addObject(object);
            }
            is.close();
            fi.close();
            return screen;
        }
        catch(OptionalDataException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.eof);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

The screen and item objects both implement Serializable and the eof is returning false with integers following the background image. The item objects all have buffered images that I have made draggable on the jpanel. Since buffered images aren't really serializable, I am removing the images from the objects and then writing them to the file, then re adding them after the write is done for continued use and trying to remake them when the item object is read in.

Too much hidden code here, e.g. Screen and Item

In general, when you have a List<Serializable> then just serialize the List. One writeObject operation

The documentation for ImageIO.read says: “The InputStream is wrapped in an ImageInputStream.”  Once an InputStream has been wrapped in an ImageInputStream, you cannot reuse the underlying InputStream, as the ImageInputStream may have read ahead for buffering or seeking purposes.  (In fact, passing an InputStream to just about any wrapper class makes the original InputStream unusable.)

@VGR I tried switching the ImageIO.read statement to come after the InputStream reads the items but it still gives me the same error, so it is not because ImageInputStream read ahead. I am sure that I can get around it by creating constructors to remake the Item objects and storing just the parameters in a list or array but I would like to know why this is happening so that I might learn something from it.

@VGR Nevermind, when I commented out the code for the background it started working, so now I have to figure out how to get the background image saved to the file.

I figured it out. I was turning the entire file I was writing to into a png just for the background image which messed up everything that came after. I saved the File object containing the background image instead and that seems to work.
